# Should I use SSD for a big multi user Access

Tags: performance

I would really like ur opinion on this subject.
I have this case.
About 10 mde (Access Programs) with around 2GB of Access Databases
A lot of Code and a lot of data...i have tables with 2 million records
These programs are used from about 70 users
We are talking about a LOT reads and writes.
It is natural that my old Dell Server with 3 SCSI 33.6gb (raid 5) is showing its age...and so the million dollar question is..should i go to SSD
Does SSD have good behavior under continous and heavy usage.Anyone having a success story.
Also should i buy Enterprise SSD($1000 each) or consumer editions ($250)
Dell is good but the SSDs its selling are too expensive....4 x 50GB = $4000 instead of maistream MLC 4 x 250 = $1000 (Yes i am considering raid 10)

Comment: is your disk i/o your bottleneck? doubt it. it's MSJet

Answer (score 2):

No.

The Jet engine has some interesting performance tweaks in it, and can provide very basic multi-user access but trying to use it across a network and/or trying to support concurrent users on it is like using a teaspoon to mix concrete. There's nothing wrong with teaspoons - its just the wrong tool for the job.

Port the data to a proper multi-user DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle....there are lots of products available, MySQL and PostgreSQL are free) then connect the applications via ODBC (note that for bulk operations you'll not see significant performance benefits without using the SQL pass-thru).

C.

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle both offer "free" Express editions which allow you to put your toe in the water, so to speak.

Comment: +1 for original and picturesque analogy.

Comment: It would be great if i could move to sql but i am talking about 200 tables,500 queries and equal forms and reports..and the code is BIG...plain simple forms with NO fancy graphics and the MDEs exceed 150MB...i am talking about thousands of spaggeti like code ....so it is a big task... i estimated that its best it would require 3 years of development to move to .NET.
So for the time lets stick to the current status and talk about SSDs and Access MDBs

Comment: Switching the database backend requires **no code changes** and there are automated tools for migrating your schema and data (e.g. http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php).

Comment: There is a small change...u can check urself....it needs dbSeeChanges